# Python: Trying to create a json object with dict (TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable User object)

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to make a full JSON object return from the module, which gets all users from database and enters their data in one JSON object, but I get `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable User object`, I don't really know what's the problem.

```
from application.models import User


class users_eng:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_users(self):
        users = User.query.all()

        # users output - [<User 9nematix>, <User 3nematix>, <User 6nematix>]

        for user in users:
            users_data = {
                dict(
                    username=user.username,
                    bio=user.profile_bio,
                    role=user.role,
                    profile_picture=user.profile_picture
                ) for user.username, user.profile_bio, user.role, user.profile_picture, *_ in users
            }

        x = json.dumps(users_data)
        print(x)

        return x

_users_ = users_eng()
```

** EDIT: I updated my code with the other solution in comments, but now I get `[<generator object users_eng.get_users.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000001AF38C828C8>]`

```
from application.models import User
from flask import session
import json


class users_eng:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_users(self):
        users = [
            User.query.all()
        ]

        # users output - [<User 9nematix>, <User 3nematix>, <User 6nematix>]
        users_data = []
        for user in users:
            users_data.append(
                dict(
                    username=user.username,
                    bio=user.profile_bio,
                    role=user.role,
                    profile_picture=user.profile_picture,
                ) for user in users
            )

        print(users_data)

        return users_data

_users_ = users_eng()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user object is not an iterable type. Typically, database models are not. You need to change `for user.username user.bio ...` to just `for user`

Additionally dicts are unhashable, so you will encounter another error after fixing the first. I would recommend making your `users_data` an array of dicts, instead of a dict

Example:

```py
# Ignore this, substitute with your own model
from database.models import User

users = [
    User(email="foo@bar.com", first="Foo", last="Bar")
]

users_data = [
    dict(
        email=user.email,
        name=f"{user.first} {user.last}",
    ) for user in users
]
```

An additional example converting this back to a valid JSON object

```
from json import dumps

from database.models import User

users = [
    User(email="foo@bar.com", first="Foo", last="Bar")
]

users_data = [
    dict(
        email=user.email,
        name=f"{user.first} {user.last}",
    ) for user in users
]

# This is valid JSON
rv = dumps({"users": users_data})
print(rv)
```

Output:

```
{"users": [{"email": "foo@bar.com", "name": "Foo Bar"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I receive not JSON format -  `[<generator object users_eng.get_users.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000001AF38C828C8>]`

Comment: Yeah, apologies, I made a mistake in the code and edited it accordingly. Try the new edited version.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'username'`

Comment: it should be - `users = User.query.all()`

Comment: Thanks man, maybe you know any fast solution to remove [] in the JSON?

Comment: If you really need your output in JSON format, I'd recommend putting that new array in a dict like `{ "users": users_data}` and then dumping that to JSON

Comment: Hmm, I tried this, but this is not the way to do it :D For real I don't work with dicts and arrays so much so I don't know how it's done..

Comment: `users_data = [
            dict{
                username=user.username,
                bio=user.profile_bio,
                role=user.role,
                profile_picture=user.profile_picture
            } for user in users
        ]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211892/discussion-between-nikolaus-gullotta-and-dzitc).